# Python | Weak performance while searching in big file using "threading"

Tags: python, multithreading, search

I'm a newbie in Python. Help me please with performance issue.
I'm working on a program that generate string and search it in a big text file (~1 GB).

Without multi threads program loads about 8% CPU (6 pCPU; 16 GB RAM) and proceed about 800 cycles per second.
2 threads ("threading" module) load about the same 8% CPU and proceed about 400 cycles per second each.
Increasing of threads don't increase whole speed/performance.

Example of the program:

```
import threading

text_file = 'C:/Work/text_file.csv'

def compute (ThreadNumbers):
    for i in range(100000):
        gen_string = <generation>

        if gen_string in file_read:
            print('SUCCESS')

with open(text_file, 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    file_read = f.read()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=compute, args=("1"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=compute, args=("2"))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Is it possible to increase the performance?

Thank you.

Comment: CPython has a global interpreter lock. Only a single thread will run at a time

Comment: I think you will need to use `multiprocessing` and partition the file in multiple chunks then search each chunk with its own process or something like that, either how, as I have read: "If you want performance, don't use Python" (I mean Python is great and all but it is relatively slow compared to other programming languages)